# SQL: how to check that any 2 columns out of 9 columns have the same value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-athena

I have 9 binary columns (value 0/1). I need to filter out rows from the entire table where any of those 9 columns have a value of 1. So I'm using:

```
select * 
from T 
where (colA = 1 or colB = 1 or colC = 1 or colD = 1 or ...... colH = 1 or colI = 1)
```

But any of these 2 columns can also have value 1 at same time, for example `colA = 1 and colB = 1` at the same time. So to check these on 9 columns I've to write this query like 55 times.

How can I write a query such that it will look for any 2 among all 9 which have the same value and count its number.

Comment: *I need to filter out rows ...* is not the same as *write a query such that it will look for any 2 among all 9 which have the same value and count its number*. Explain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you essentially want:

```
 where (colA + colB + colC + colD + colE + colF + colG + colH + colI) = 2
```

If by "binary" you mean `bit`, you need to convert them:

```
where ( convert(int, colA) +
        convert(int, colB) +
        convert(int, colC) +
        convert(int, colD) +
        convert(int, colE) +
        convert(int, colF) +
        convert(int, colG) +
        convert(int, colH) +
        convert(int, colI)
      ) = 2
```

Comment: Sorry to miss out, there might be the case where 3 columns have value 1. and by binary I meant that the values in these columns are 0 or 1.

Comment: On the other hand, I can use your first query and have the sum as 1 instead of 2, because that's what I want. I want only 1 of those 9 columns have a value of 1.

Comment: @ParasPasrija . . . You can adjust the sum for what you want.